# Make flag counters in flag dashboard sidebar clickable

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools, per-site-meta, flag-dashboard

It doesn't happen too often on my sites, but sometimes there's a flag on the meta site instead of the main site. In that case, the sidebar of the flag dashboard shows a widget like this:

[image]

The problem with it is that only the phrase "Meta Flags" is clickable; it would make sense for the flag counter to be clickable as well. After all, the flag counter in the top bar *is* clickable:

[image]

It's not just Meta flags; I've noticed other widgets in the sidebar have the same problem.

[image]

Comment: Have you considered becoming a beta/meta tester for the company? :)